# Creating Vue instance comments out everything

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create an Chrome extension with [web accessible resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources). Since my extension tries to create a modal with a list of available data, I decided to use VueJS to handle the dynamic nature of content.

However, When I create the sample files and initialize VueJS, it simply leads to all the DOM being commented out and my app not working.

Here's the code I'm using:
**web_resources/vue.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_resources/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/web_resources/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**web_resources/app.js**

```
window.app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello World'
  }
})
```

When I run this, the entire `div` is replaced with:  `<!---->` and nothing works.

On searching online for VueJS inside iframe, I came across [this post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-inside-iframe/6419) which has this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/ohznser9/) which surprisingly produces a blank page for me with no content. On inspecting the result, I find that the `div` has been replaced with `<!---->` here as well.

Why is VueJS not initializing properly within an iframe?

Comment: The fiddle [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/0ju4L59r/) if `{{{` is changed to `{{`; the template was wrong. Have you checked the console?

Comment: Oh. Maybe its not the same issue then. Yes, I have checked the console and it only produces my console message saying: `Ran app.js successfully`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Content Security Policy (CSP). Since I was using a local copy of `vue.min.js`, I couldn't see any of the error messages. It looked like everything was initializing as expected except it wasn't. Once I replaced this with a un-minified version, I saw an error on the lines of:

[image: CSP Error]

I simply had to go update the CSP in `manifest.json` which I was able to do by adding:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
```